# Run browser-sync in php server

Tags: php, server, browser-sync

I have a `XAMPP` local `PHP` server and I need use browser sync but I don't know how to run it WITHOUT gulp or grunt only using command line.  I try to

```
browser-sync start --server --port 80 --files "css/.css"
```

but instead of port 80 it launch with 81 port

`browser-sync start --proxy 'localhost:80'` I tried this. It's connect to my localserver but doesn't refresh

Comment: browser-sync start --proxy 'localhost:80' I tried this. It's connect to my localserver but doesn't refresh

Comment: Same problem here. Browsersync works fine, it opens the browser on port 3000 (or 81) but it doesn't refresh upon saving a file in Sublime3. Port 80 doesn't work, it always listens to 81 but I think that's not a issue in this case. It's just it does not refresh anything.

Comment: it's not refreshing because you have to navigate to your `xampp/htdocs` folder and run the script there, since the `--files` argument expects a relative path on your local system. It is **NOT** relative to server path `localhost`!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `--files` argument. There should be an **asterisk** before `.css` to select *all* CSS files in your css directory, like this:

```
browser-sync start --proxy "localhost:80" --files "css/*.css"
```

Remember that the directory path should be **relative to the current directory you're inside in your terminal/cmd window**.

This means that if your server is running on `localhost` and CSS files can be found under `localhost/css`, it is ***NOT*** enough to just run the browsersync script above from any directory.

You have to navigate to your local server folder (usually `C:\xampp\htdocs`, where your real `css` folder is located) and run the browsersync script from there. Alternatively, if you don't want to change the directory in your console/terminal/cmd window, you have to specify the full relative path to your CSS files from your current directory.

Had the exact same issue, and I just had to run the script from the correct folder path.